# Getting internal error when do this while loop for RSS feed

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I try that write a RSS feed with php+mysql but i get internat error 500 and i'm sure that it is from while loop ,thanks for your help.

The codes:

```
$result = mysql_query($query_site_archive);

while ($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $details = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
   <title>'. $article["title"] .'</title>
   <link>http://localhost/website/'. $folder .'/details.php?articleid ='. 
         $article["articleid"] .'&parentid ='. $article["parentid"] .'&catid ='. 
         $article["catid"] . '</link>
    <description>'. $article["description1"] .'</description>'
}

echo '</channel></rss>';

echo "$details";
```

Comment: comment out the $details assignment and the echo at the bottom. Try echoing $article and pasting the results here.

Comment: the echo is :   echo '</channel>  
</rss>';

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query_site_archive);

while ($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $article."\n";
}

What does that yield?

Comment: what is problem for this line that you mentioned?

Comment: Just give me the output of the code I posted, please? I want to make sure you're getting out what you think you are.

Comment: i know that the query must return 30 records and with your codes i get:30Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array Array

Comment: What's your 500 bad request error in httpd logs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok... Now try `echo $article["title"]."\n"`?

Comment: i get all 30 title of articles.

Comment: please note that there are some codes missing in my question ,i don't know why after putting enter it has missed ,inside while loop it is codes for rss.

Comment: Ok... make sure you have the rest of the elements you want in the same way.

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query_site_archive);

while ($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){



   $details = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0">
     <channel>
      <title>'. $article["title"] .'</title>
      <link>http://localhost/PersianPersiaPHP/'. $folder .'/details.php?articleid ='. $article["articleid"] .'&parentid ='. $article["parentid"] .'&catid ='. $article["catid"] .'</link>
      <description>'. $article["description1"] .'</description>'
     }
  
echo "</channel>\n";
echo "</rss>\n";

echo "$details";

Comment: Perhaps the [Universal PHP feed generator](http://ajaxray.com/blog/?p=48) will be the solution to your problems, as it looks like your data is fine.

Comment: yes, my data is ok ,how can i use the codes that are in you link?